# A problem with .bib file or related

Tags: bibliographies, xetex, compilation-error

I have copied the `Bibliography.bib` into CWD but still getting the following error.
Can someone please suggest a solution to this ?

```
Command Line:   makeindex.exe "main2.idx"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl\Y

This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2021/W32TeX] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning input file main2.idx...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Nothing written in main2.ind.
Transcript written in main2.ilg.


Command Line:   makeindex.exe -s "main2.ist" -t "main2.glg" -o "main2.gls" "main2.glo"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl\Y

Index style file main2.ist not found.
Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcg] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]


Command Line:   xelatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "main2.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl\Y

This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main2.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-11-22> (./kaobook.cls
Document Class: kaobook 2021/06/02 v0.9.7 kaobook
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbook.cls
Document Class: scrbook 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script document class (book)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile-hook.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlogo.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize10pt.clo)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty)) (./kao.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/colortbl/colortbl.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvipsnam.def))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xifthen/xifthen.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifmtarg/ifmtarg.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/options/options.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
(|extractbb --version))))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xpatch/xpatch.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/afterpage.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/imakeidx/imakeidx.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/multicol.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/varioref.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlayer-scrpage.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlayer.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ragged2e/ragged2e.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/setspace/setspace.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyphenat/hyphenat.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-xetex.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/needspace/needspace.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xspace.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/placeins/placeins.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/marginnote/marginnote.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/marginfix/marginfix.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sidenotes/sidenotes.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption-koma.sto)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/changepage/changepage.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chngcntr/chngcntr.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/footmisc/footmisc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/footnotebackref/footnotebackref.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref-langpatches.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/stringenc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty))))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex)
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex)
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-xetex.def
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def))
))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric
.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.t
ex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithm
etics.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.cod
e.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code
.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.c
ode.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code
.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
 (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.st
y)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.st
y)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarytopaths.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tikzpagenodes/tikzpagenodes.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/rotating.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/floatrow/floatrow.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoc/etoc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook-2020.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-xetex.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-table.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/morewrites/morewrites.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/morewrites/primargs.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bookmark/bookmark.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bookmark/bkm-dvipdfm.def))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/enumitem/enumitem.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdframed/mdframed.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zref/zref-abspage.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zref/zref-base.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdframed/md-frame-1.mdf))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eso-pic/eso-pic.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/ppxetex.def))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfiles/subfiles.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/import/import.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/todonotes/todonotes.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarypositioning.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithm2e/algorithm2e.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/relsize/relsize.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ccicons/ccicons.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/metalogo/metalogo.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mfirstuc/mfirstuc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xfor/xfor.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-base.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/substr/substr.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-fp.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp.sty
`Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/defpattern.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-basic.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-addons.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-snap.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-exp.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-trigo.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-pas.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-random.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eqn.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-upn.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eval.sty))))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries-compatible-307
.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-hypernav.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-list.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-long.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-super.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/supertabular/supertabular.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-tree.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nomencl/nomencl.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/dialogue.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/blkcntrl.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/moredefs.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecmds/makecmds.sty)

LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook 'file/after/tracklang.sty' is deprecated.
(hooks)              Use hook 'file/tracklang.sty/after' instead.


LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook 'package/after/bidi' is deprecated.
(hooks)              Use hook 'package/bidi/after' instead.


LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook 'package/after/luabidi' is deprecated.
(hooks)              Use hook 'package/luabidi/after' instead.

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-latex.ldf))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-english.ldf)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.cfg))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/mathrsfs.sty)
Writing index file main2.idx
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/indentfirst.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fncychap/fncychap.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/blindtext/blindtext.sty) (./kaobiblio.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bigfoot/perpage.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/iflang.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-unicode.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric-comp.cbx)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)))
(./kaotheorems.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thmtools.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-patch.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/parseargs.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-kv.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-autoref.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/aliasctr.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-listof.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-restate.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-amsthm.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thmdef-mdframed.sty))
(./kaorefs.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cleveref/cleveref.sty))
Writing index file main2.idx
(./glossary.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrhack.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/floatrow.hak)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/listings.hak)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/nomencl.hak)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/setspace.hak))

LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [a4paper,fontsize,twoside,numbers].

No file main2.aux.
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/ltcaption.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty))

Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/floatrow/fr-longtable.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdflscape/pdflscape.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/lscape.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/lscape.hak))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/american.lbx
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty) (./main2.bbl
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msa.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msb.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd) [1] (./main2.mw)
[2] (./main2.mw) [3] (./main2.mw) [4] (./main2.mw)

Package hyperref Warning: old toc file detected, not used; run LaTeX again (che
ers from etoc).

[5] (./main2.mw) [6] (./main2.mw)

Package hyperref Warning: old lof file detected, not used; run LaTeX again.


Package hyperref Warning: old lot file detected, not used; run LaTeX again.

[7] (./main2.mw) [8] (./main2.mw)
part without number
[1] (./main2.mw) [2] (./main2.mw)
part without number
[3] (./main2.mw) [4] (./main2.mw) (./pref.tex
chapter A.

Class scrbook Warning: odd/even page label number 1 undefined on input line 3.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'bringhurst:2002' on page 5 undefined on input line 12.


! Undefined control sequence.
l.12 ...he Elements of Typographic Style}'' \citep
                                                  {bringhurst:2002}.
? ^C
! Interruption.
<to be read again> 
                   {
l.12 ...e Elements of Typographic Style}'' \citep{
                                                  bringhurst:2002}.
? X
fwrite: Invalid argument
xelatex.exe: 

_____________________________________________________________________

 PDFTeXify Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

 Errors: 2   Warnings: 11   Bad Boxes: 0
_____________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: `\citep` undefined? Did you give `natbib=true` to `biblatex`?

Comment: do you have a makeindex style `main2.bst` ?

Comment: you are specifying a custom index style `makeindex.exe -s "main2.ist" ` but  makeindex reports `Index style file main2.ist not found.`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please how technically can I make `main2.bst` and what can I do about your second comment to make it correct for `Winedt 10.3` ?

Comment: @DaiBowen Where can I pass to `xetex` `natbib=true` to `biblatex` ?

Comment: It's a `biblatex` package option

Comment: I can not tell you what style you want, just delete `-s "main2.ist"` if you do not need a custom style. If you had some instructions saying to use `-s "main2.ist"` the instructions must have said what to put in it, that is specifying non standard settings specific to the document, but impossible to guess what settings you want