# XeTeX compilation is just cycling indefinitely

Tags: xetex, compiling, compilation-error

I have a strange problem: a `main2.tex` file which was previously OK and after
pressing F9 key compiled and showed the result in AR now strangely enough
cycles forever. Whats wrong with it ? I have just interrupted it and copied to
clipboard the output. I'm interested in successful compilation with pdf output.

```
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref-langpatches.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/stringenc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty))))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex)
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex)
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-xetex.def
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def))
))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric
.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.t
ex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithm
etics.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.cod
e.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code
.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.c
ode.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code
.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
 (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.st
y)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.st
y)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarytopaths.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tikzpagenodes/tikzpagenodes.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/rotating.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/floatrow/floatrow.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoc/etoc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook-2020.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-xetex.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-table.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/morewrites/morewrites.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/morewrites/primargs.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bookmark/bookmark.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bookmark/bkm-dvipdfm.def))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/enumitem/enumitem.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdframed/mdframed.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zref/zref-abspage.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zref/zref-base.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdframed/md-frame-1.mdf))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eso-pic/eso-pic.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/ppxetex.def))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfiles/subfiles.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/import/import.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/todonotes/todonotes.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarypositioning.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithm2e/algorithm2e.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/relsize/relsize.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ccicons/ccicons.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/metalogo/metalogo.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mfirstuc/mfirstuc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xfor/xfor.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-base.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/substr/substr.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-fp.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp.sty
`Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/defpattern.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-basic.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-addons.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-snap.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-exp.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-trigo.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-pas.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-random.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eqn.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-upn.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eval.sty))))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries-compatible-307
.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-hypernav.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-list.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-long.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-super.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/supertabular/supertabular.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-tree.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nomencl/nomencl.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/dialogue.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/blkcntrl.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/moredefs.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecmds/makecmds.sty)

LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook 'file/after/tracklang.sty' is deprecated.
(hooks)              Use hook 'file/tracklang.sty/after' instead.


LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook 'package/after/bidi' is deprecated.
(hooks)              Use hook 'package/bidi/after' instead.


LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook 'package/after/luabidi' is deprecated.
(hooks)              Use hook 'package/luabidi/after' instead.

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-latex.ldf))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-english.ldf)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.cfg))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/mathrsfs.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.ltd.tex))
Writing index file main2.idx
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/indentfirst.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/blindtext/blindtext.sty) (./kaobiblio.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bigfoot/perpage.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/iflang.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-unicode.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric-comp.cbx)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)))
(./kaotheorems.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thmtools.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-patch.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/parseargs.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-kv.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-autoref.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/aliasctr.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-listof.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-restate.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-amsthm.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thmdef-mdframed.sty))
(./kaorefs.sty (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cleveref/cleveref.sty))
Writing index file main2.idx
(./glossary.tex) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fncychap/fncychap.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrhack.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/floatrow.hak)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/listings.hak)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/nomencl.hak)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/setspace.hak))

LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [a4paper,fontsize,twoside,hypertexnames,parskip,numbers].

(./main2.aux (./selectors.aux

LaTeX Warning: Label `eq:pyth' multiply defined.


LaTeX Warning: Label `eq:pyth@cref' multiply defined.

) (./appendix.aux))
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex

Package geometry Warning: The marginal notes overrun the paper.
     Add 17.32088pt and more to the right margin.

*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: xetex
* paper: custom
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: twoside 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(71.7013pt, 418.25148pt, 107.55196pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(101.4061pt, 591.5271pt, 152.1092pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50473pt
* \paperheight=845.0424pt
* \textwidth=418.25148pt
* \textheight=591.5271pt
* \oddsidemargin=-0.5687pt
* \evensidemargin=35.28197pt
* \topmargin=-3.86389pt
* \headheight=15.0pt
* \headsep=31.29787pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=42.0pt
* \marginparwidth=112.03273pt
* \marginparsep=12.8401pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidetrue
* \@mparswitchtrue
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

*geometry* verbose mode - [ newgeometry ] result:
* driver: xetex
* paper: custom
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: twoside 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(70.56247pt, 304.44289pt, 222.49937pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(77.96011pt, 689.12218pt, 77.96011pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50473pt
* \paperheight=845.0424pt
* \textwidth=304.44289pt
* \textheight=689.12218pt
* \oddsidemargin=-1.70752pt
* \evensidemargin=150.22939pt
* \topmargin=-40.60774pt
* \headheight=15.0pt
* \headsep=31.29787pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=42.0pt
* \marginparwidth=135.71892pt
* \marginparsep=17.6406pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidetrue
* \@mparswitchtrue
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/ltcaption.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/floatrow/fr-longtable.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdflscape/pdflscape.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/lscape.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/lscape.hak))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/american.lbx
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty) (./main2.bbl
)
*geometry* verbose mode - [ newgeometry ] result:
* driver: xetex
* paper: custom
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: twoside 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(70.56247pt, 456.37979pt, 70.56247pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(77.96011pt, 689.12218pt, 77.96011pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50473pt
* \paperheight=845.0424pt
* \textwidth=456.37979pt
* \textheight=689.12218pt
* \oddsidemargin=-1.70752pt
* \evensidemargin=-1.70752pt
* \topmargin=-40.60774pt
* \headheight=15.0pt
* \headsep=31.29787pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=42.0pt
* \marginparwidth=0.0pt
* \marginparsep=0.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidetrue
* \@mparswitchtrue
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msa.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msb.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd) [1] (./main2.mw)
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 280--280

[2] (./main2.mw) [3] (./main2.mw) [4] (./main2.mw) [5] (./main2.mw) [6]
(./main2.mw)
*geometry* verbose mode - [ newgeometry ] result:
* driver: xetex
* paper: custom
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: twoside 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(70.56247pt, 304.44289pt, 222.49937pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(77.96011pt, 689.12218pt, 77.96011pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50473pt
* \paperheight=845.0424pt
* \textwidth=304.44289pt
* \textheight=689.12218pt
* \oddsidemargin=-1.70752pt
* \evensidemargin=150.22939pt
* \topmargin=-40.60774pt
* \headheight=15.0pt
* \headsep=31.29787pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=42.0pt
* \marginparwidth=135.71892pt
* \marginparsep=17.6406pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidetrue
* \@mparswitchtrue
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

(./selectors.tex [1] (./main2.mw) [2] (./main2.mw)
chapter 1.

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 18--27

[3] (./main2.mw)
Overfull \hbox (3.13332pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 82--84
[]\TU/LibertinusSerif(0)/m/n/10 Are there large classes of sequences for which 
$[][]$ can decide whether
[4] (./main2.mw)
chapter 2.

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 188--195

[5] (./main2.mw)) [6] (./main2.mw)
part without number
[7] (./main2.mw) [8] (./main2.mw)
*geometry* verbose mode - [ newgeometry ] result:
* driver: xetex
* paper: custom
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: twoside 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(70.56247pt, 304.44289pt, 222.49937pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(77.96011pt, 689.12218pt, 77.96011pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50473pt
* \paperheight=845.0424pt
* \textwidth=304.44289pt
* \textheight=689.12218pt
* \oddsidemargin=-1.70752pt
* \evensidemargin=150.22939pt
* \topmargin=-40.60774pt
* \headheight=15.0pt
* \headsep=31.29787pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=42.0pt
* \marginparwidth=135.71892pt
* \marginparsep=17.6406pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidetrue
* \@mparswitchtrue
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

(./appendix.tex
chapter A.

Package hyperref Warning: bookmark level for unknown mtocsection defaults to 0.



Overfull \hbox (0.26108pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 30--32
[]\TU/LibertinusSerif(0)/m/n/10 There were some other people present and one of
 them

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 58--69

[9] (./main2.mw)) [10] (./main2.mw)

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'simpson2' on page 11 undefined on input line 350.

[11] (./main2.mw) [12] (./main2.mw)
*geometry* verbose mode - [ newgeometry ] result:
* driver: xetex
* paper: custom
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: twoside 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(70.56247pt, 456.37979pt, 70.56247pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(77.96011pt, 689.12218pt, 77.96011pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50473pt
* \paperheight=845.0424pt
* \textwidth=456.37979pt
* \textheight=689.12218pt
* \oddsidemargin=-1.70752pt
* \evensidemargin=-1.70752pt
* \topmargin=-40.60774pt
* \headheight=15.0pt
* \headsep=31.29787pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=42.0pt
* \marginparwidth=0.0pt
* \marginparsep=0.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\foo 
------------
------------
Running 'xdvipdfmx -E -o "main2.pdf"  "main2.xdv"'
------------
Latexmk: Examining 'main2.log'
=== TeX engine is 'XeTeX'
Latexmk: applying rule 'xdvipdfmx'...
main2.xdv -> main2.pdf
[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10][11][12][13][14][15][16][17][18][19][20][21]
119717 bytes written
Latexmk: Summary of warnings from last run of *latex:
  Latex found 2 multiply defined reference(s)
  Latex failed to resolve 1 citation(s)
Latexmk: All targets (main2.xdv main2.pdf) are up-to-date


Command Line:   bibtex.exe "main2"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl\Y

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX)
The top-level auxiliary file: main2.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file main2.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file main2.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file main2.aux
(There were 3 error messages)


Command Line:   makeindex.exe "main2.idx"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl\Y

This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2021/W32TeX] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning input file main2.idx...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Nothing written in main2.ind.
Transcript written in main2.ilg.


Command Line:   makeindex.exe -s "main2.ist" -t "main2.glg" -o "main2.gls" "main2.glo"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl\Y

Index style file main2.ist not found.
Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcg] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]


Command Line:   latexmk -xelatex --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "main2.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl\Y



_____________________________________________________________________

 PDFTeXify Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

 Errors: 0   Warnings: 0   Bad Boxes: 0
_____________________________________________________________________
```

**EDIT**

```
\documentclass{kaobook}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\titleimage{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{gfx/TFZsuperellipse_bw}}

\frontmatter
\title{Your Title}
\author{Your Name}
\maketitle

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
Your content goes here.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I suggest that you reduce your document to a minimal one that has this behavior and ask about that piece. Right now, people only get the log and can only guess.

Comment: You can start by fixing the obvious warnings such as `LaTeX Warning: Label `eq:pyth' multiply defined.`  and `LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [a4paper,fontsize,twoside,hypertexnames,parskip,numbers].`

Comment: Probable based on log: you are running bibTeX, but your document requires Biber. (Unless you configured Biblatex otherwise, Biber is default.) `latexmk` appears to be cycling through rules, but there are files it doesn't know how to make e.g. `main2.ist`. But it doesn't look as if `xelatex` is looping itself.

Comment: @cfr How could I fixed that `.ist` issue most easily ?

Comment: Without any information about your document whatsoever, that is hard to say, but you could try just omitting the `-s` option and use `makeindex`'s default style. But if this is for `glossaries`, it depends on your setup and direct use of `makeindex` might be easier. `makeglossaries`, perhaps. But, honestly, how should we guess what you're trying to do?

Comment: @cfr I cannot detect the problem with cycling through rules. The code is [here](https://pastebin.com/UEhXRx9F). It would be great if you could detect the problem. Feel free to ask for any additional files. so that you can compile it.

Comment: So make a minimal example which demonstrates the problem and post it. But start by fixing all the other errors and warnings people have pointed out and are shown in the log.  I don't debug entire projects for free ;).

Comment: See what @DavidCarlisle told you in May, for example (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/686442/a-problem-with-bib-file-or-related#comment1703429_686442).

Comment: @cfr Please look at my EDIT. It gives to me this error: `(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-tree.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nomencl/nomencl.sty)))
! Undefined control sequence.
l.12 \titleimage
                {\includegraphics[width=6cm]{gfx/TFZsuperellipse_bw}}
? Terminating on signal SIGINT(2)


_____________________________________________________________________

 PDFTeXify Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

 Errors: 2   Warnings: 0   Bad Boxes: 0
_____________________________________________________________________

`

Comment: @cfr Ihink that my last example in the EDIT is a MWE .

Comment: You haven't defined `\titleimage` so you get an error.